# Keras training model to find the sum of two numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, linear-regression, keras-layer

Trying to implement a very simple training model to predict the sum of two numbers using tensorflow keras.
I tried with Single Dense Layer.
I tried changing no of epochs as well. 
I tried changing optimizer to linear as well.
But nothing worked out for me to give me the best accuracy.

Below is the code What I tried so far and the output that I got.

**Import**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from random import randrange
```

**Generate Training Data**

```
trainingInput = [[i, i + randrange(5000)] for i in range(1, 5000)]
trainingOutput = [(input [0] + input [1]) for input  in trainingInput ]

testInput = [[5, 5], [1, 9], [2, 5], [6, 3], [1, 4]]
testOutput = [10, 10, 7, 9, 5]
```

**Build the model**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

**Compile the model**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.mae, metrics=['mae'])
```

**Training**

```
model.fit(trainData, trainOutput, batch_size=5, epochs=50)
```

**Final Evaluation and Prediction**

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(testData, testOutput)
print("Test Accuracy : ", test_acc)
a = np.array([[3, 3000], [4, 5], [1,10], [2,10],[5,9], [4,10], [1,15]])
print(model.predict(a))
```

**Output**

```
[[2994.769   ]
[   8.959281]
[  10.961123]
[  11.956481]
[  13.944955]
[  13.947194]
[  15.949196]]
```

Can anyone help me improve my training model and accuracy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try increasing the number of layers, the number of units in each layer & train for a bit longer.

Comment: Ok @Aditya Mishra Let me add two more layer with some more no of units and lets see.

Comment: I disagree with @Aditya Mishra - this is a trivial task and having 0 hidden layers is more appropriate. In this case, the model would be: y = w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + b, and it should learn w1=w2=1 and b=0. Other than this, when you print your "test accuracy", you are actually showing the mean absolute error (that's what mae stands for), so the lower the better.

Comment: model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', input_shape=(2,))), model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.2), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              metrics=['mse']). I tried this way also but not getting better result

Comment: What do you mean with "not getting better result"? How do you evaluate the performance?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a smaller learning rate - so the gradient will not "jump" too much - meaning a finer tuning of the weights. I also added a simple linear activation and some negative examples for the model to be more general:

```
trainingInput = np.array([[randrange(5000)-2500,  randrange(5000)-2500] for i in range(1, 50000)])
trainingOutput =  np.array([(input [0] + input [1]) for input  in trainingInput ])

inp = Input(shape=(2,), name='inp')
out = Dense(1, activation='linear',name='out')(inp)
model_sum=Model(inp,out)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model_sum.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mae'])

model_sum.fit(trainingInput, trainingOutput, batch_size=100, epochs=50,verbose=2)

a = np.array([[3, 3000], [4, 5], [1,10], [2,10],[5,9], [4,10], [1,15]])
print(model_sum.predict(a))
```

output:

```
Epoch 45/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.0166 - mae: 0.0166
Epoch 46/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.0184 - mae: 0.0184
Epoch 47/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.0164 - mae: 0.0164
Epoch 48/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.0151 - mae: 0.0151
Epoch 49/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.0161 - mae: 0.0161
Epoch 50/50
 - 0s - loss: 0.0161 - mae: 0.0161

 [[3002.9626  ]
 [   8.99987 ]
 [  10.999748]
 [  11.999768]
 [  13.999842]
 [  13.999809]
 [  15.999686]]
```

you can also compile the model again with a lower learning rate (by a factor of 10), and get it more and more accurate. don't build the model again - just the optimizer definition, compile and fit:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001)
model_sum.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mae'])

model_sum.fit(trainingInput, trainingOutput, batch_size=100, epochs=50,verbose=2)

a = np.array([[3, 3000], [4, 5], [1,10], [2,10],[5,9], [4,10], [1,15]])
print(model_sum.predict(a))

Epoch 47/50
 - 0s - loss: 9.9272e-11 - mae: 9.9272e-11
Epoch 48/50
 - 0s - loss: 1.5182e-10 - mae: 1.5182e-10
Epoch 49/50
 - 0s - loss: 1.5532e-10 - mae: 1.5532e-10
Epoch 50/50
 - 0s - loss: 4.5265e-10 - mae: 4.5265e-10

 [[3003.]
 [   9.]
 [  11.]
 [  12.]
 [  14.]
 [  14.]
 [  16.]]
```